# MVC 5 Razor view template binding hide script to a model radiobutton

Tags: javascript, razor, model, asp.net-mvc-5, editorfor

Currently have a custom EditorTemplate which dynamically populates based on the incomming Model () in the Razor page.
The aim is to be able to hide the individual **div** '**Sub_Text**' in the editor template based on the radio value.

Model: Prime.cs

```
public class Prime{
    public List<QuestionModel> Questions { get; set; }
}
```

Model: QuestionModel.cs

```
public class QuestionModel{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Question { get; set; }
    public string Answer  { get; set; }
    public string SubText { get; set; }
}
```

Main View: _Reporting.cshtml

```
@model ViewModels.Prime

@for (int i = 0; i < Model.Questions.Count(); i++) //Dynamically generate and model bind database PolicyHolderKeyQuestions
{
    @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Questions[i], "QuestionModel")
}
```

EditorTemplate: QuestionModel.cshtml

```
@model ViewModels.QuestionModel
@{
    <div class="col-lg-2">
        @Html.RadioButtonFor(Model => Model.Answer, YesNoNAOptions.Yes)
        @Html.RadioButtonFor(Model => Model.Answer, YesNoNAOptions.No)
        @Html.RadioButtonFor(Model => Model.Answer, YesNoNAOptions.NA)
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-9">
        <div class="row">
            <p>
                    <strong>@Model.Question</strong>
            </p>
        </div>
        <div class="row" name="**Sub_Text**"> @* **Hide Me!** *@
            @Model.SubText
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

So far the closest idea I have found is to add a script something like this to the bottom of the template:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(':radio[name=Answer').change(function () {
        // read the value of the selected radio
        var value = $(this).val();
        var doc 
        if (value == 1) {
            $('#Sub_Text').show();
        }else{
            $('#Sub_Text').hide();
        }
    });
</script>
```

Which seems to be able to work for something simpler without using @Html.EditorFor() in a loop.

It looks as if the script does not follow the same automatic naming changes as those that happen to the RadioButtonFor elements. Resulting in things like this:
Radio:

```
<input id="Questions_0__Answer" name="Questions[0].Answer" type="radio" value="No" />
```

While the divs and scripts keep referencing only what was directly entered.

How can you dynamically hide the "**Sub_Text**" **div** based on the radiobutton when it is nested in this way?

If there is a way to do this without feeding in a script per EditorFor radio group that would be even better, but all solutions are welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap the html generated by the `EditorTemplate` in a container so that you can use relative selectors

```
@model ViewModels.QuestionModel
<div class="question"> // container
    <div class="col-lg-2">
        @Html.RadioButtonFor(Model => Model.Answer, YesNoNAOptions.Yes)
        ....
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-9">
        ....
        <div class="row">@Model.SubText</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and then the script can be

```
$(':radio').change(function () {
    // get the associated element containing the SubText value
    var row = $(this).closest('.question').find('.row');
    if ($(this).val() == 1) {
        row.show();
    } else {
        row.hide();
    }
});
```

Side note: If your `QuestionModel.cshtml` is in the `/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates` or `/Views/yourControllerName/EditorTemplates` folder (which it should be) then the code in `_Reporting.cshtml` should be just

```
@model ViewModels.Prime
@Html.EditorFor(x => x.Questions)
```

No loop is required. The `EditorFor()` accepts `IEnumerable<T>` and generates the correct html for each item in the collection.

Comment: Thanks Stephen for leading me down the right trail.
I found that to apply the script across all of the generated radio groups it had to begin in this way: 
`$(':radio').change(function () {`